# pushViewController doesn't work programmatically with storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

When i push a view using the segues (directly by dragging it on the storyboard) it works fine, and the next view is loaded. However, when i try to implement all this programmatically to push a view when i click on the right arrow of the PIN (in Maps), i am a bit confused:

**EDIT**

```
 -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: enseigneDeLaStation");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifer:@"You identifier" sender:self];
}
```

i got this error:

```
Receiver Type 'MyFirstViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector performSegueWithIdentifer:sender:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `UIViewController`s instance method `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. It initiates the segue with the specified identifier from the view controller’s storyboard file programmatically.

[Here is the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW83).

Example code would be: (assuming you are calling this in a view controller.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your identifier" sender:self];
```

So for your code it would be:

```
-(IBAction)goToNextView{
    NSLog(@"The button is clicked");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your identifier" sender:self];
}
```

Don't forget to set the segue identifier in the interface builder. Also, do make sure that you have the same identifier in both your code and the interface builder.

Comment: Hi Pfitz, could you please illustrate me a use example? thanx in advance

Comment: Pfitz, Actually, i try it before commenting but i got an error: `Receiver Type 'MyFirstViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector performSegueWithIdentifer:sender:`, also, i try to push the view when click on the right arrow of the PIN when using the Map, so my code is on the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method, i am going to update my post to make my question clear.

Comment: Hi @Pfitz, my post is updated, also, it seems i should make a segue identifier in storyboard, if so,where should i identify it?

Comment: Hi @Malek. Click on the segue in the story board and open the attributes inspector on the right side of Xcode. There you can set the identifier of the segue.

Comment: Hi @Pfitz: i have gived an identifier to my segue, now i am getting this warning: `Instance method -performSegueWithIdentifer:sender: not found (return type defaults to id)`, am i missing something?

Comment: message is spelled wrong, should be performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

missing an "i"

Comment: This is very useful and helped a lot but I still have a question to ask : to give an identifier to a segue you need to create a segue between two views in the interface builder. how can you create a segue like this if you don't want it to run when you don't click on a map pin ?

Comment: Since this is not "your" question i would kindly recommend to you, that you ask you question with a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Malek is correct. Pfitz example does return

> Receiver Type 'MyFirstViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector performSegueWithIdentifer:sender:

This is due to an typo. The correct method is

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"You identifier" sender:self];
```